# How to set default device Alarm tone for scheduled notification?

Tags: android, notifications, alarm

I want to set default device alarm tone for my scheduled notification as normal notification sounds are hard to notice.

I try to get alarm tone by: `Uri alarmTone = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);`

and then simply set it with: `builder.setSound(alarmTone);`

All I get is vibration with out any alarm tone sound. Any ideas?

Whole code:

```
private Notification getNotification(String content) {
    Uri alarmTone = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            this,
            Receiver.NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID
    );
    builder.setContentTitle("Title");
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.x);
    builder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX);
    builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS);
    builder.setSound(alarmTone);
    builder.setContentText(content);
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);

    return builder.build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Code:

```
1.builder.setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI);
2.mBuilder.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your preferred alarm in "Res\raw\{your_ringtone}.mp3"

and then do like this:

```
Notification mNotification = builder.build();
mNotification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://"
            + context.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.{your_ringtone});
```